# How to do math in PHP echo result

Tags: php

The issue I have which I need help with is in the following if:

```
<td>
     <?php 
         if($result['Job']['no_of_searches']<'5')
         {
              echo '<span class="badge bg-warning">100</span>';
         }

         if($result['Job']['no_of_searches']>'5')
         {
              echo ‘PROBLEM-IS-HERE’;
         }
     ?>
</td>
```

In the PROBLEM-IS-HERE field I want to display a math result from:

```
<?php echo $result['Job']['no_of_searches']; ?> / <?php echo $result['Job']['total_autoaccepted']; ?> * 100
```

But how can I do this?

Comment: What is your problem and what kind of error you have in your code?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of `$result[$x][$y]`.

- If it is a string, like suggested by the code of [developercoolio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4309411/developercoolio), it has to be converted to an integer with the PHP function `intval()` before performing numerical operations on it. In that case, however, the string comparison `<'5'` could be unappropriate, because the string '10' is considered to be lower than the string '5', which is certainly not the behaviour that you expect.
- If it is an integer, the code should be rewritten as follows

  ```
      if($result['Job']['no_of_searches'] < 5)
       {
           echo '<span class="badge bg-warning">100</span>';
       }
       if($result['Job']['no_of_searches'] > 5)
       {
          echo (int) (($result['Job']['no_of_searches'] * 100) / $result['Job']['total_autoaccepted']);
       }
  ```

Comment: Be aware that, if `$result['Job']['no_of_searches'] == 5`, nothing will be executed.

Comment: When I do this, I get this error: Warning (2): Division by zero

Comment: I you get a division by zero, it means that the expression `$result['Job']['total_autoaccepted']` is undefined or, if defined, equal to zero

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  echo (($result['Job']['no_of_searches'] / $result['Job']['total_autoaccepted']) * 100);
 ?>
```

Comment: You can't expect to get any help if you do not provide enough information. An error message would be a start.

Comment: The statement should be correct, see here: https://3v4l.org/VlXvG You problem could be somewhere else.

Comment: Attention: 1) do not repeat the `<?php` tag inside a php code, and 2) first multiply by 100 and then divide, otherwise you loose a lot of precision.

Answer (score 0):

Change it from `if($result['Job']['no_of_searches']<'5')` to `if($result['Job']['no_of_searches']<5)`

Comment: Im pretty sure thats not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want instead of (int) you can replace your data type like float

Answer (score 0):

You can change data type instead of int like float

```
<?php echo (((int)$result['Job']['no_of_searches']/(int)$result['Job']['total_autoaccepted'])*(int)100)  ?>
```